# Sharepoint 2010 Search core result

Tags: my-site, xslt, search-results

Is there any way we can link the "Author" field that is displayed in "search core results" (not People Core Search Results) to their corresponding "My Site"? I tried using the managed property to display the author's username but it does not return any value. Please help. Thanks in advance

Using XSLT!!

I created managed property called "MySiteUrl" and mapped it to the "People:PersonalSpace(Text)". Then I did full crawl and added property in "Fetched Properties" in Web part properties as . My result in XML looks like 

`<All_Results>
 <Result>
 <id>1</id>
 <workid>329</workid>
 <rank>18</rank>
 <mysiteurl></mysiteurl>
 <title>searchtry</title>`

As you can see MySiteUrl did not return any values. Please advice on what I am doing wrong. Does Search Core result web part support the "People:" crawled properties? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySite url is stored in "PersonalSpace" field in User Profile. So create a managed property for mysite url and mapped that property to "People:PersonalSpace(Text)".

Then use this property in Core Search Results webpart to set the link for the Author name.

Comment: Remember to do a full crawl after creating the managed property.

Comment: Yes, thanks James for pointing Full Crawl. After creating the property, run the full crawl of the Content Source to affect the search results.

Comment: I created managed property called "MySiteUrl" and mapped it to the "People:PersonalSpace(Text)". Then I did full crawl and added property in "Fetched Properties" in Web part properties as <Column Name="MySiteUrl"/>. My result in XML looks like
<All_Results>
    <Result>
      <id>1</id>
      <workid>329</workid>
      <rank>18</rank>
      <mysiteurl></mysiteurl>
      <title>searchtry</title>
As you can see MySiteUrl did not return any values. Please advice on what I am doing wrong. Does Search Core result web part support the "People:" crawled properties? Thanks.